# State functions and change in state functions

Tags: thermodynamics

So, I have been studying thermodynamics, in it I read that state functions are those functions which depend only on one state of the system and are independent of the path taken, which is pretty easy to understand. And this clears why properties like enthalpy, pressure, volume etc are state functions.
Then there was the statement,

> Change in a state function is not a state function.

which took me some time to understand, but I got it once I referred to the original definition of a state function. But now when I read about Hess law, which basically states that change in a state function is independent of the path taken, I'm confused as doesn't this imply that change in state function is infact a state function. Can someone please clarify this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is delta H a state function?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/26532/is-delta-h-a-state-function)

Comment: @Poutnik i had seen this answer to clarify my doubt regarding why change in state function is not a state function but this doesn't clarify my doubt regarding hess law

Comment: If you do not comment you have seen it, it is like if you have  not seen it. // The Hess law is about different paths between 2 given states, leading to path independent change. If one of the states changes, the change value changes, not being function solely of a single given state. The single state is the key, not the change being independent on the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine hiking scenario and the elevation as the state function of your position.

The elevation value for given location does not depend on the way how you have got there nor on any parameter not defined by the state, therefore it is a state function.

OTOH, your elevation change when getting there depends on the initial point and does not depend solely on the destination. Therefore the state function (elevation) change is not state function.

If, like in the Hess law , both the initial and final states are given, then the difference in the respective state function values (elevation change) does not depend on the path taken from the initial to the final point.

As state function change depends on two states, not on the current state only, it is not a state function. Multiple initial states, leading to the common final state, would mean multiple state function value changes for the same state.

Comment: Thanks for the amazing explanation. So to be classified as a state function, the function must be only dependent on the state of the system, while the condition that it is independent of the path taken may not be enough to say that the function is a state function. Is this correct?

Comment: State function = function of state, not function of state + other factors.